# несколько таблиц созданных динамически объединить

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Будет несколько таблиц, которые создаются динамически название `name` и динамический суффикс `xxx` - `name_XXX`. Можно ли выбрать все таблицы с базы только с этим динамическим суффиксом. и объединить их в одну таблицу - главную `app_name`.

Динамические таблицы создаются при регистрации и суффикс `xxx` записывается в таблицу `user`

Подскажите как это можно реализовать на `yii2` Куда  копать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерный код в контроллере:

```
        $out = "";//Просто сбор данных
        $dbname = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT DATABASE()")->queryScalar();//Получаем название текущей DB
        $suffix = "_suffix";//Ваш суффикс
        $connection = \Yii::$app->getDb();
        $command = $connection->createCommand("SHOW TABLES");//Возможно потребуется Show table in db_name
        $result = $command->queryAll();
        foreach ($result as $item)
        {
            $table = $item["Tables_in_" . $dbname];
            //Поиск вхождения суффикса в имя таблицы
            if(strstr($table, $suffix))
            {
                //Тут ваш дальнейший код, я просто сохраняю в переменную и позже вывожу
                $out .= "<p>{$table}</p>";
            }
        }
        echo $out; die();
```

Comment: спасибо  тебе добрый человек